# html/php create and save text file to root directory with custom filename

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I want to create a text file through my website page with a self-define filename. Can it be done with only html or php is needed?

Here is my code:

```html
 <form id="raw-text" >
     <textarea name="raw" rows="10" id="raw" style="word-wrap: break-word; resize: horizontal; height: 700px; width: 99%"></textarea>
    </form>
    <input id=“filename" placeholder="File Name here"></input> 
    <button name="submit" onclick="form.echo()" >Send!</button>
```

Comment: If you want to create the file in your server, you'll need a server side script for that.

Comment: Your `<input>` and `<button>` (which should be `<input type="submit">` instead) aren't inside the `<form>`. The `<input>` also has no `name` attribute, which is required to make the value accessible by PHP. There's a wrong quote `“` at the start of `“filename"`. The button's `onclick` is set to a JS call, but you didn't post the JS code. As for your question, this can easily be done by a) creating a form that sends the necessary info to the server b) writing PHP code that creates the file based on that info. This is PHP form handling 101, which you can learn all over the internet.

Comment: *"create and save text file to root directory"* - there are some serious security implications with doing this; tread cautiously.

Comment: Yes, if you are creating a file from user input you will need to validate absolutely everything to ensure it is secure. For example, if your index.php file is created at the root, could someone just overwrite that file? Can they create a file with a .php extension? If so, they basically have access to do anything within PHP that you could do. They could exploit everything. My suggestion would be to find a different way to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: Actually, I forgot to say that those txt files will be saved at another  directory instead of index's "root directory".But sure, I will have a program to check for "insecure" files and remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML can't create files.

Assuming you have a single file (let's call it “index.php”), here is an example of code necessary to deal with both the server-side php code and the client-side html code.

```
<?php
    if( $_POST["name"] || $_POST["data"] ) {
        $name   = $_POST['name'];
        $data   = $_POST['data'];

        if(file_exists($name)){
            // Do something if file already exists

        }else{
            // Creates file if it doens't exist
            file_put_contents($name , $data);
        }
        exit();
    }
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <form action = "?" method = "POST" id="raw-text" >
            <textarea name="data" rows="10" id="raw" style="word-wrap: break-word; resize: horizontal; height: 700px; width: 99%"></textarea>
            <input name="name" placeholder="File Name here"></input> 
            <button name="submit">Send!</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The above is capable of creating a file and inserting the data typed by the user.
If the php script is in a separate file, you can change the 
`<form action = "?"` to `<form action = "Path_To_File"`.

Note that:
`$_POST['…']` retrieves the named html tags from the form.
See http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php for details about the file_put_contents php function.

But, I agree with comments, this is not a secure way to do.
This code is an example and you need to test many things to make it secure and implement it in your application.
And you need to be sure that the files that the users will be creating aren't system files or php files that allow them to do anything they want.

Comment: This is not a secure way of doing this.

Comment: @Takit Isy `<?php
    if( $_POST["name"] || $_POST["data"] ) {
        $name   = $_POST['name'];
        $data   = $_POST['data'];
  static $ext    = ".txt";
  $n      = rand();

        if(file_exists($name)){
   //rename exist file with random string
   $filename = $name + $n + $ext ;
           file_put_contents($filename , $data);

        }else{
   $filename = $name + $ext ;
            // Creates file if it doesn't exist
            file_put_contents($filename , $data);
        }
  //header("Location: /memosmemes/index.php");
        exit();
    }
?>` Is this correct?

Comment: @Tenent Jason `<?php
 if( $_POST["name"] || $_POST["data"] ){
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $data = $_POST['data'];
  static $ext = ".txt";
  if(file_exists($name)){ //rename exist file with random string
   $n = rand();
   $filename = $name.$n.$ext;
  }else{
   $filename = $name.$ext ; // Creates file if it doesn't exist
  } 
  file_put_contents($filename , $data);
  header("Location: /memosmemes/index.php");
  exit();
 }
?>` will be nicer. `rand()` only used if necessary, concatenation of strings with `.`, and only one apparition of `file_put_contents(…)`. Seems correct, yay. :)

Comment: `$filename = $name.$n.$ext; ` Seems like the rand() is not working.It overwrite the old file with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, you should not let the user create files based on their input; especially letting the user set file names based on input.

If they created a **.php** file and then browsed to it, you would be allowing them to run their own PHP code on your server.  This allows them a great amount of access to your system.  They could also add **.htaccess** files, or **.ini** files, which would be very bad as well.

The number of checks you would need in order to ensure the correct data is entered and that the files could not be used to exploit your system would be huge, and you would almost certainly miss something that could be exploited.  The best answer is to not allow this and to find a different way to do what you want.